# Google Cloud Functions Python Sessions: "The session is unavailable because no secret key was set"

Tags: python, google-cloud-functions

I have created a simple login script that I want to host on [Google Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions).

The application works fine when I run it locally because I then run **app.py** which uses `app.secret_key` and starts a Flask app with `app.run(...)`.

However when running on Goolge Cloud Functions the starting point is the function `main(request=None)`. This does not start a Flask App. Because of this a secret_key is not set and I get the error "The session is unavailable because no secret key was set".

How can I solve this problem?

**app.py - Only used locally**

```
import os

import flask
from flask import request
from flask_cors import CORS

import main

app = flask.Flask(__name__)

cors = CORS(app)
app.config['CORS_HEADERS'] = 'Content-Type'


@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    print("index()")
    return main.main(request)


# - Main start ----------------------------------------------------------------
if __name__ == "__main__":

    # Sessions
    app.secret_key = os.urandom(12)
    app.run(debug=True, host="0.0.0.0", port=8080, ssl_context=('certificates/cert.pem', 'certificates/key.pem'))
```

**main.py - The entry point for the Google Cloud Function**

```
import json
import os

import flask
from flask import session

from src.pages.login import login


def main(request=None):
    print("main()")

    # Logged in?
    if not session.get('logged_in'):
        return login(app)
    else:
        return "logged in!"


    # Finish
    return {"message": "completed successfully"}


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**src/pages/login.py**

```
from flask import request, session


def login(app):
    print("login() :: Init")

    # Get :: Process
    process: int = int(request.args['process'])

    # Process == 1
    if process == 1:

        # Fetch username and password
        inp_username: str = ""
        inp_password: str = ""
        try:
            login = request.form

            inp_username = login['inp_username']
            inp_password = login['inp_password']

        except Exception as e:
            print(f"login() :: Process error when getting request form e={e}")

        # Test username and password
        if inp_username == "admin" and inp_password == "admin":
            print("login() :: Welcome")

            # Sessions
            session['logged_in'] = True
            return "Welcome"
        else:
            print("login() :: Wrong password")
            return "Wrong password"



    return '''
    <form method="post" action="?process=1" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <p>Username:<br />
        <input type="text" name="inp_username" value="" />
        </p>
        
        <p>Password:<br />
        <input type="password" name="inp_password" value="" />
        </p>
        
        <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Login" />
        </p>
        
    </form>
    '''
```

Answer (score 0):

You are right that the main function acts as the entry point rather than **app.py** when executing your Flask application on Google Cloud Functions rather than the latter directly. Because the Flask app is not launched using **app.run()**, the **app.secret_key** variable is not set.

When using Google Cloud Functions, you may alter your main function to construct and launch the Flask app and configure the **app.secret_key**.

```
from flask import Flask, session

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'secret_key'

@app.route('/route')
def your_function():
    session['key'] = 'value'
    data = session.get('key')
    return '=response'

def main(request):
    with app.test_request_context(request.path, headers=request.headers):
        response = app.full_dispatch_request()
    return response
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last): File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2528, in wsgi_app response = self.full_dispatch_request()


raise TypeError(f"{type(self).__name__!r} objects are immutable")

Comment: I get the error: Error: could not handle the request

Comment: Is the session kept locally? I mean on Cloud Functions side? Or it's a cookies and the session content is stored on client side (and forwarded with each request)?

Comment: Google Cloud Functions does not have any storage.